# How to set up PyInstaller in PyCharm for a project using External Tools inside venv?

Tags: python, pycharm, exe, pyinstaller, external-tools

I have a project in PyCharm with multiple Python files, as well as some text files, which I want to export into .exe via PyInstaller (I'm on Win 7). The project uses some external modules installed inside `venv` via pip (PyInstaller is one of them).

[image: external tools settings]

I want to keep things simple and not use any modules outside `venv` in the build, for obvious reasons. However, when I try to execute the PyInstaller tool on the project folder, I get a permission error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`. Using PyInstaller on the `main.py` inside the project builds it just fine at first glance, but running the .exe in `cmd` shows an `error loading Python DLL`. How do I do it right? Something tells me the spec should be created beforehand to include all files and modules used in the project.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, the `Arguments` you specify in PyCharm are passed to `pyinstaller.exe` when you execute the tool. So it should be the path to `main.py` or the path to your `.spec` file, not `$FilePath$` which is a macro that gets replaced by the file that is currently open in PyCharm.

You should definitely have a `.spec` file, that is committed to version control. This makes your PyInstaller builds more consistent, and allows others to reproduce them easily. See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html